# Error CS1585: Member modifier 'public' must precede the member type and name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, overriding, monodevelop

Guys I was working on Unity3D's MonoDevelop. I was implementing my classes however I got an error I cannot figure out what is. The problem I get is in the title at the line where I override the abstract methods proceed and isFinished. What is the problem?

```
namespace tool
{

    public class TaskManager
    {
        public TaskManager ()
        {
        }
    }

    public abstract class Task {
        public bool isEvitable = true;
        public abstract void proceed();
        public abstract bool isFinished();
    }

    public class MoveTask : Task {
        float speed;
        Vector3 targetPosition;
        GameObject movingObject;

        private MoveTask(GameObject gameObject, float speed, Vector3 target) {
            this.movingObject = gameObject;
            this.speed = speed;
            this.targetPosition = target;
        }

        @override
        public void proceed() {
            Vector3 objPos = movingObject.transform.position;
            movingObject.transform.position = new Vector3 (Mathf.Lerp(objPos.x, targetPosition.x, speed),
                                                           Mathf.Lerp(objPos.y, targetPosition.y, speed),
                                                           Mathf.Lerp(objPos.z, targetPosition.z, speed));
        }

        @override
        public bool isFinished() {
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: never used override myself, but a quick google would suggest using : public override void proceed() ... it seems @override is java but you are using c# ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this. yours is java syntax.

```
public override void proceed(){
}

public override bool isFinished(){
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This helped me a lot :) The IDE I work on is MonoDevelop and it misleads me too much :S it has never emphasized the line where @override is. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ExploitAPI api ; new ExploitAPI

     public ExploitAPI Api { get => api; set => api = value; }


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            api.LaunchExploit();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            api.ToggleClickTeleport();
        }
    }
}
```

please answer the fix as soon as possible

Best regards, guest